# ResourceNotFoundException error when accessing image in Android Titanium module

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm developing an Android Module for a Titanium app and I have to generate a Notification. Android SDK forces me to do a `setSmallIcon()` call to include a png asset as icon for the notification. I've put **icon_notification.png** asset in **/platform/android/res/drawable** folder of my module and (tryed to) got it in the code calling

`TiRHelper.getResource("drawable.icon_notification")`

but when I build module calling ant, the following error is raised:

```
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Running Kroll binding generator.
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] No binding data found, creating new data file: org.appcelerator.titanium.bindings/connecthings.json
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for proxy Beacon
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Found binding for module Connect
[javac] Note: [KrollBindingGen] Generating JSON: file:/Users/***/Development/***/modules/android/***/android/build/generated/json/org/appcelerator/titanium/bindings/***.json
[javac] warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kroll.checkTiContext]'
[javac] /Users/***/Development/***/modules/android/***/android/src/***/***/***/***/ConnectModule.java:76: error: unreported exception ResourceNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[javac]             .setSmallIcon(TiRHelper.getResource("drawable.icon_notification"))
[javac]                                                ^
[javac] Note: /Users/***/Development/***/modules/android/***/android/src/***/***/ti/***/BeaconProxy.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 1 error
```

seems that raising a `ResourceNotFoundException` exception, builder doesn't find the assset

Have I placed the file in the wrong place?

Comment: Hi claudio, sdk version?

Comment: The latest one both for appc CLI and Titanium SDK: **5.2.2**, and module is built with **android-23** and **addon-google_apis-google-23** android SDK and **android-ndk-r11b** Android NDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error posted is trowed during build step of the module. 
In this step I think that resources are not already put in place, so, wrapping the TiRHelper method in a try...catch statement as written in the wiki suggested by @Saeed Sharman resolve the problem.

So, the working version is simply:

```
try {
  TiRHelper.getResource("drawable.icon_notification");
catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The platform folder also has to sub-folder of android folder.The full directory is "android/platform/android/res/drawable/". You can also check if the resources are created in the build folder.

[Documentation Link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Project#AndroidModuleProject-PlatformFolder)

Comment: The folder is the same in which I'veplacedthe asset (as you can read in my description). The link you posted refers to an older version of the platform because ```TiRHelper.getApplicationResource``` is no longer documented as you can see in the reference http://docs.appcelerator.com/module-apidoc/latest/android/index.html.